# Is there a way to get list/details of installed c# templates without using the cli?

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

I know I can get a list of templates using the dotnew-cli by typing dotnet new -list, but I am trying to get the same information in a windows program I am working on.

So simply put I am looking for the same way that Visual Studio will list all available templates. Do I need to parse the template folder directly?

Comment: Why not just call dotnet.exe and capture the output?

Comment: I could, but that method is very prone to breaking due to unforseen consequences. So I was hoping there would be a better way.